# web3 python convert addresses from transaction log topics

Tags: web3.py

I'm trying to get the to and from address from the logs in a transaction.
In my example, the log entry is for a Transfer(address,address,uint256).

The resulting topics[1] and [2] return the addresses, but in a long format:
0x0000000000000000000000002dbbbebef9915110dac11a89ca986ba6051d0972

How do I convert this to a regular address? Eg:
0x2dbbbebef9915110dac11a89ca986ba6051d0972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `address` stores the given address.

---

**Option #1 - purely in Python:**

Since an Ethereum address is 40 hexadecimal characters, you can simply use

```
x = '0x' + address[-40:]
```

---

**Option #2 - with web3.py:**

Using the utility function [toChecksumAddress](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.main.html#web3.Web3.toChecksumAddress), you can simply use

```
x = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x' + address[-40:])
```

---

The second option is better because it gives you the result in standard (EIP55) form, which means that you can compare your addresses (strings) without worrying about case-sensitive differences.

Comment: Thank you. Option 2, whilst I agree would be preferable, gives me an error:`ValueError: Unknown format 0x00000000000000000000000......` 
Option 1 works great. I guess I could do option 1 and then option 2 to vefiy the address.

Comment: @Julian: Please see updated answer.